# How to hide associated nodes with taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, theming

I've created `taxonomy-term--example.tpl` to theme all terms within this vocabulary. I got one problem: beside the term fields, the page shows all the associated nodes (the nodes that has a term reference to my currently displayed term).

How to prevent the nodes from showing up on my page ?

Comment: Remove the part that renders them? I don't quite get what's problematic about it. Could you post your code?

Comment: because you cannot control the rendering of associated nodes from `taxonomy-term--example.tpl` , anyway, i found a module `taxonomy term display` and solved it